# CSS Template Selector for generic id

Tags: dom, css-selectors, jsonp, jsoup

I have multiple tables in my file and I want to search only those tables that have `id = table-<SOME_VALUE>`

for specific `id(table)` I am using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements tableRows = doc.select("#table");
```

Please suggest me if there is any option to find all those tables that starts with 'table-'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for my problem

```
doc.select("table[id^=table-]");
```

Reference Link:

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp